# How do i end a while loop with blank input(str)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to make a program that you can add string to a list. For example 'Apple'. It sorts them into alphabetical order and ends the loop on a empty input

I've tried expect valueErrors and SyntaxError none of them work for string.
I've also tried if(str(input) == Null) but that diden't work as id expect or want

```
try:
    ostos = []

    while True:
        ostos.append(str(input("Lisää listalle:")))
        print("Listalla on", len(ostos), "riviä:")
        ostos.sort()
        print(ostos)

except:
    print(ostos)
```

It would as for a input into the list. It would add Apple, Banana and Orange to the list. Put them in alphabetical order every input. And it would end on a empty input

Lisää listalle: Apple
Listalla 1 riviä:
Apple
Lisää listalle: Orange
Listalla 2 riviä:
Apple, Orange
Lisää listalle: Banana
Listalla 3 riviä:
Apple, Banana, Orange
Lisää listalle:
Listalla 3 riviä: 'Empty'
Apple, Banana, Orange

Comment: Empty string is a valid string. You shouldn't expect it to raise any exception. Check for empty string and break loop if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```py
ostos = []

while True:
    string = str(input("Enter something:  "))
    if string != '':
        print("You entered blank")
        break
    else:
        ostos.append(string)
        continue
```

This also works:

```py
if len(string) == 0: break
```

The first one simply checks if the user input is blank, which will be the case if the user presses enter. The second one checks if the length of the entered string is 0,which only happens if user presses enter.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this way without `if`.

```
ostos = []

s = input("Lisää listalle:")
while s:
    ostos.append(s)
    print("Listalla on", len(ostos), "riviä:")
    ostos.sort()
    print(ostos)

    s = input("Lisää listalle:")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check if passed string is empty and break loop:

```
ostos = []

while True:
    s = input("Lisää listalle:")
    if not s:  # check that s is not empty
        break   # break loop if is empty
    ostos.append(s)
    print("Listalla on", len(ostos), "riviä:")
    ostos.sort()
    print(ostos)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

ostos = []

while True:
    input_data =  str( input("Input :" ))
    if input_data.rstrip() == "" :
        break

    ostos.append( input_data )

    ostos.sort()
    print(ostos)
```

Comment: FYI, your indentations are all wrong. This code does not produce the output required and raises a syntax error